# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

When my application tries to make a database connection:

```
            _conn = new OracleConnection(_connString);
            _conn.Open();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException occurred
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
       at MyCorp.Middleware.Common.DataAccess.OracleDataAccess.OpenConnection() in C:\DevProjects\MyCorp\Solutions\MyApp\trunk\Middleware\Common\DataAccess\OracleDataAccess.cs:line 46
InnerException:
```

Here is my tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:     E:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = CLRExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
  )
)

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.sub.mydomain.com)
  )
)
```

Here is listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
    (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    (ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
    (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
  )
)

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )
)

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\oracle
```

Here is my connection string in the config file:

```html
  <add name="ConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = orcl)));User Id=testuser;Password=testpwd;"
         providerName="OracleODP-11-2.0" />
```

I can connect no problem to the database using sqlplus on the command line.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Why is my oracle connection failing?  It was working before, I'm just not sure what I changed to cause it to fail now.

Comment: Much easier for you would be to switch to managed ODP.NET, rather than trying to deal with version inconsistencies, dll missing, etc. in unmanaged version of ODP.NET - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: Yes, that is what we would like to do, but we are presently using nHibernate, so we have a lot of technical debt right now, which means that we are stuck with Oracle 11g and the native Oracle client.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Nhibernate as of version 4 supports the managed ODP.net driver.  I've already used it.  It really does a nice job because you don't have to worry about the over 100 MB of oracle files that had to be copied to your bin.  Why is the above code not Nhibernate code if you are using NHibernate?

Comment: We are using nHibernate 3.1.  Our goal is to remove nHibernate completely and write our own ORM layer, but that is further down the road.  I haven't looked into what it would take to upgrade to nHibernate 4.

Comment: If you are using 3.1, you can just create your own driver implementation and copy in the managed oracle driver from 4 (https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Driver/OracleManagedDataClientDriver.cs).  Then just register the new driver in your config.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Also your provider name looks wrong.  It's the ODP.net OracleConnection.  It doesn't need a provider.

Comment: Could you please tell me, will the managed oracle driver you mentioned work with spring?

Comment: in what regard?  is spring your IoC you are using?  it really shouldn't matter.  What matters is the that NHibernate can instantiate your new driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Fran, for your suggestions.  Didn't get the go-ahead from my team to try to implement the managed solution.  Instead, just re-installed oracle on a fresh virtual machine with the native client which worked.